# The value of $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}(x)$ and its limit as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

> Calculate $I_{n}=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^{2n}(x)\,{\rm d}x$
>   and show that  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} I_{n}=0$

Should I separate $\cos^{2n}$ or I should try express it in Fourier series?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: @flawr Should I seperate cos^{2n} or I should try express it in Fourier series?

Comment: The limit is $$\lim_{x\to\infty}I_n=I_n$$ since $I_n$ is constant with respect to $x$

Comment: Put cos(x) = [exp(ix) + exp(-ix)]/2 and note that in the binomial expansion of the 2nth power all terms integrate to zero except for the constant term. You thus have I_n = 2 pi/2^(2n) Binomial(2n,n)

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Comment: First note that 

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^{2n}x dx = 4 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2n}xdx$$

Now, we use the [identity][1] $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2n}xdx = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\frac{\pi}{2}$ and we have

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^{2n}x dx = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\cdot2\pi$$


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Additional_identities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a completely 
elementary 
(i.e., nothing beyond basic integration)
proof.

Taking advantage of
the symmetries of
$\cos$,
$I_{n}
=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^{2n}(x)\,{\rm d}x
=4\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n}(x)\,{\rm d}x
=4\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2} (\cos^2(x))^{n}\,{\rm d}x
=4\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2} (1-\sin^2(x))^{n}\,{\rm d}x
$.
Since
$\sin(x)
\ge 2 x/\pi
$
on
$0 \le x \le \pi/2$,
$I_{n}
\le 4\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2} (1-(2x/\pi)^2)^{n}\,{\rm d}x
= 2\pi\int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)^{n}\,{\rm d}x
= 2\pi\int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)^{n}\,{\rm d}x
$.

Split the integral into two part,
$\int_0^d$ and $\int_d^1$.
In the first part,
since the integrand
is at most $1$,
the integral
is at most $d$.
In the second part,
the integrand 
is at most
$(1-d^2)^n$,
so the integral is less than
$(1-d^2)^n$.
We now want to relate $d$ and $n$
so both integrals are small.

To make
$(1-d^2)^n
< c
$,
where
$0 < c < 1$,
we want
$n\ln(1-d^2)
< \ln c
$
or
$n(-\ln(1-d^2))
> (-\ln c)
$
or
$n
> \frac{-\ln c}{-\ln(1-d^2)}
$.

Therefore,
for any positive
$c$ and $d$,
by choosing
$n
> \frac{-\ln c}{-\ln(1-d^2)}
$
we can make
$I_n
<
2\pi(d+c)
$.
By choosing $c$ and $d$
arbitrarily small,
so is $I_n$,
so $\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n
= 0$.

To get a more elementary
bound on $n$,
since
$-\ln(1-z)
>z
$
if $0 < z < 1$,
$\frac{-\ln c}{-\ln(1-d^2)}
<\frac{-\ln c}{d^2}
$.
so choosing
$n > \frac{-\ln c}{d^2}$
will do.

To completely eliminate $\ln$s
in the bound for $n$
set $c = 10^{-m}$.
We get
$I_n < 2\pi(d+10^{-m})$
by choosing
$n
>\frac{m \ln 10}{d^2}
$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $|\cos(x)| \leq 1$, we can use the Dominated convergence theorem on the sequence of functions: $f_n(x)=(\cos(x))^{2n}$. But $f_n \rightarrow 0$ a.e. on $[0,2\pi]$, and so by DCT we have that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}I_n=0$

Comment: Haha. That was $n\to \infty$ and I was out with a paper doing some weird stuff. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

It is with little difficulty to show that
\begin{align}
I_{n} = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \cos^{2n}\theta \, d\theta = 2 B\left(\frac{1}{2}, n + \frac{1}{2} \right).
\end{align}
Using Stirling's approximation it can be shown that 
\begin{align}
I_{n} \rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{4 \pi}{n+1}}  \hspace{5mm} n \rightarrow \infty
\end{align}
which leads to 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} I_{n} \rightarrow 0.
\end{align}